# What is the proper usage of "x (read y)" where y is another word/phrase for x?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

I've often seen this used for humorous purposes, but I would assume it has a formal usage as well.

Example:

> Mortos (read mooch) is a demon from the Spooky Realm.

As far as I can tell, it's basically used as an "aka" or "i.e." of sorts, but I didn't want to assume I knew how it worked, and start throwing around all the time while people shake their heads at me silently.
I had no idea how to search for this, so I'm hoping somebody can tell me what this is called as well.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/do-you-pronounce-read-in-management-read-fools-like-reed-or-like-red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's informally referred to as a *[parenthetical read](https://www.quora.com/When-an-author-inserts-a-mid-sentence-parenthetical-that-begins-with-read-is-it-pronounced-reed-or-red)* (also discussed [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/162666/Is-the-parenthetical-read-pronounced-reed-or-red)).

In some contexts, it's a form of *[videlicet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/videlicet)*.